# Can I return, from ajax, what should javascript do?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript:

```
  $.get("/ajax/config-switch.php", { 'edit' : edit, 'id' : id },
     function(data){
        if (data[0] == 'success'){
           $('#tooltip-hovered').html(data[1]);
        }
     },'json'
  );
```

What I want to do, however, is to return this line:

```
$('#tooltip-hovered').html(data[1]);
```

from PHP, instead of having it in javascript. So `config-switch.php` file would end with something like:

```
<?php

if ($success){
echo json_encode(array('success', "$('#tooltip-hovered').html(data[1]);"));

?>
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: If you are trying to dynamically load a tooltip,I will recommend not do it this way just load it statically!. But if you are trying to replace the js code with php for some other reason it will not work! once the page is loaded how will it request the server for later requests? you should use ajax!

Comment: Looks like a terrible idea... like the beginning of a post-apocalyptic maintenance hell. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute JS code just from the server response. The php file should return some correct JS code, and it should be executed.

Try to use as *dataType* the **script** instead of *json*. So your JavaScript will be like:

```
$.get(
    '/ajax/config-switch.php', 
    {'edit': edit, 'id': id},
    function(data) {
        console.log('callback');
    }, 
    'script'
 );
```

And the corresponding PHP block:

```
<?php

if ($success)
{
    echo "$('#tooltip-hovered').html('some value');";
}

?>
```